# How to remove second row of menu entries (or is it a toolbar)?

Tags: init-file, start-up, menu-bar

I have installed OpenSuse Tumbleweed and later Emacs.

If I start Emacs from the shell,

```
$ emacs -Q
```

I have a double row of menu entries

```
File - Edit - Options - ... - Help
New File - Open - Open Directory - ... - Search
```

In a sense, the buttons in the second row are not menus, because they directly invoke simple commands…

I'd like to get rid of the second menu row, maintaining the first one.

I checked the `~/.emacs` that was automatically installed, apparently nothing relevant, and I've also tried `emacs -q`, to no avail.

Comment: Do you see the same problem if you start Emacs using `emacs -Q` - uppercase `Q`? (I don't.) If not, bisect your init file to find the culprit. If you do, then provide a step-by-step recipe, from `emacs -Q`, to reproduce the problem - as part of your question. Since you see this with `emacs -q` (lowercase), a guess is that it's caused by your site-wide init file, `site-start.el` - see [Entering Emacs](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Entering-Emacs.html). If so, take up the problem with your site adminstrator.

Comment: Which version of Emacs is this? Is it running in a terminal or with a graphic interface? I don't recall seeing this second menu row on any system.

Comment: @Gilles'SO-stopbeingevil'  It is Emacs 27, but it doesn't matter: it looks like it was not a real menubar but a ***text only toolbar***, very similar to a menubar!  See my self-answer below.

Comment: Please edit the question or the answer to make clear that the problem was misunderstanding that what looks like a second menu-bar row (which is entirely possible, BTW) is in reality in your case a tool-bar with textual tool-bar entries. This is clear from comments, but comments can be deleted at any time. Thx.

Comment: @Drew I have edited my answer, hopefully making clear it was a (understandable) misunderstanding.

Comment: I suggest maybe editing the question title (dunno), so people with the same question/problem might find it easier (?). Maybe mention toolbar there, as part of the question?

Comment: @Drew I'm afraid I have no idea how to edit the title to make it easier to find the question, should you have one please edit.  And, thank you for the assistance!

Comment: I edited the title.

Answer (score 1):

Oops, what I mistakenly assumed to be a second menubar was indeed the toolbar in disguise!
Here it is how I realized my mistake.

---

In OpenSuse, `/usr/bin/emacs` is a lengthy shell script that eventually starts either `/usr/bin/emacs-gtk` or `/usr/bin/emacs-x11`.

When I tried `emacs-gtk -Q` I had the same results as using the system script, so I tried also `emacs-x11 -Q` and Emacs opened a window with the menu and an iconic toolbar.

I had a moment of enlightenment noticing that the toolbar entries had a perfect match with the "menu" in the second row...

So I used `Options → Toolbar → None` and voila, the second row disappeared.

For some reason GTK rendered the toolbar buttons using text only, in a format that was virtually indistinguishable from the menu entries of the first row... and I needed to start `emacs-x11` to be enlightened because I'm not used to using the toolbar.

Answer (score 0):

You can add this to your `.emacs`:

```
(tool-bar-mode -1)
```